# How to upload file if the browse button is placed in iframe.?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I am trying to upload a file using "sendKeys" on iframe but its always opening Browse window instead of uploading file.
following is my code

```
driver.switchTo().frame(3);
WebElement UploadElement=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn"));
UploadElement.sendKeys("D:\\Report.pdf");
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you need to use sendkeys at all? if i remember correctly this can be done by using submit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530104/selenium-webdriver-submit-vs-click

Answer (score 2):

After doing much R&D i found the solution of this. I used AutoIT tool to upload file from the system if *Browse* button is placeed on the iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Directly send the file path to the id, like so

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button id")).sendKeys("D:\\Report.pdf");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath")).sendKeys("D:\\Report.pdf");
```

The above step is the answer for your first two steps

Click on Browse
Select a file to upload
For the third step(click upload), looking at the screen capture I do not see any button which says "Upload". So just click "Save" and I assume that your file will successfully get uploaded

Comment: i have updated my script like below but its still not working.  is there can be issue with iframe ?   
 driver.switchTo().frame(3); 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html[@id='ng-app']/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/div/div/button")).sendKeys("D:\\Report.pdf");

Comment: what error you getting `staleElement` or something else

Comment: i am gettinng error like "Chrome is not reachable."